# Problemas para converter data mon dd yyyy hh:mm

Tags: php, sql-server, timestamp, strtotime

Fiz um select no SQLSERVER dentro do php:

```
mssql_query(SELECT TOP 1 ven.DATA FROM tab_venda ven (nolock)
                         INNER JOIN dbo.tab_item_venda iven (nolock)
                                 ON iven.num_Venda = ven.NUM_VENDA
                        INNER JOIN dbo.tab_produto pro (nolock)
                                ON pro.cod_produto = iven.cod_produto
                         WHERE ven.tipo_venda <> 'X'
                              AND pro.Situacao = 1
                              AND (pro.ind_controle_periodo = 1 OR pro.Marca = 'RQ ETIQUETAS')
                              AND ven.COD_PESSOA = @cod_cliente
                              AND pro.cod_produto = @cod_produto
                         ORDER BY ven.DATA DESC)
```

Esse SELECT esta me retornando a data no seguinte formato: Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000 dentro do PHP. Se caso eu fiz a mesmo select direto no SQLSERVER Management Studio ele me retorna no formato: 2013-02-19 00:00:00

A primeira questão seria: Porque dentro do PHP o formato da data esta sendo: Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000?

Quando eu tento formatar a data usando:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data))
```

o resultado esta sendo: 1969-12-31

A segunda questão é, porque esta retornando a data 1969-12-31 em vez de 2013-02-19?

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar a função [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) no SQL, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT FORMAT(ven.DATA, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US') AS 'data';
```

Ou formatar no PHP:

```
$parsed = date_parse_from_format('M d Y H:i:s:B', $data); // 'Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000'
$new = mktime($parsed['hour'], $parsed['minute'], $parsed['second'], $parsed['month'], $parsed['day'], $parsed['year']);
echo date('Y-m-d', $new);
echo date('d/m/Y', $new);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Acho que isso não responde nenhuma das duas perguntas.

Comment: É uma alternativa para tratar o retorno do SELECT dela, talvez seja útil e resolva as duas questões e talvez não seja, mas não deixa de ser uma resposta, colabore com uma sua também. Abraço @JéfersonBueno

Comment: Sim, que é uma alternativa eu sei. Mas se presares atenção verá que as perguntas são: `Porque dentro do PHP o formato da data esta sendo: Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000?` e `Porque esta retornando a data 1969-12-31 em vez de 2013-02-19?`

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela ajuda, mesmo tentando formatar direto no SELECT o retorno continua no formato: Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000 acredito que é algo ligado ao formato de data no Linux, eu acho né.. num sei

Comment: Editei a resposta com a opção de formatação em PHP ve se te ajuda @LaísaFerreiraCardoso

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função `Convert`.

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 103) As Data_Hoje`

Vai retornar:

> 24/09/2015

```
SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR, ven.DATA, 103) as Data FROM tab_venda ven (nolock)
INNER JOIN dbo.tab_item_venda iven (nolock)
ON iven.num_Venda = ven.NUM_VENDA
INNER JOIN dbo.tab_produto pro (nolock)
ON pro.cod_produto = iven.cod_produto
WHERE ven.tipo_venda <> 'X'
AND pro.Situacao = 1
AND (pro.ind_controle_periodo = 1 OR pro.Marca = 'RQ ETIQUETAS')
AND ven.COD_PESSOA = @cod_cliente
AND pro.cod_produto = @cod_produto
ORDER BY ven.DATA DESC
```

Você fez isso acima e fez como no PHP ?

Quando faz isso, a data já é formatada no formato **dd/mm/YYYY**, não precisando assim, formatar pelo PHP usando `date` ou `strtotime`.

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela ajuda, mas mesmo eu tentando formatar a data dentro do SELECT o retorno continua no formato: Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000. Acredito que é algo relacionado ao servidor Linux

Comment: Atualizei meu post.

Comment: Então é essa a questão, mesmo eu formatando no SELECT o retorno dentro do PHP é Feb 19 2013 12:00:00:000 nesse formato.. mesmo formando. Se eu fizer essa query fora do PHP, dentro do Managent Studio por exemplo da certinho, mas quando joga dentro do PHP não formata.. por isso que eu acho que pode ser configuração do servidor.. eu acho

Comment: Você pode por na sua pergunta como está fazendo no PHP ? Não creio que seja o servidor...