# Formato da data no PHP vindo do SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, data

Estou executando o seguinte código:

```
$sql= mssql_query("select getdate()");
$res = mssql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

e ele está me retornando a seguinte data:

> 2015-04-10 **32767:06**

A hora esta com 5 dígitos, alguém sabe o porque?

ps. Já alterei a diretiva do `php.ini` para: `mssql.datetimeconvert = Off`

Comment: Já tentou date('d-M-Y', strtotime($datadobanco)); ?

Comment: Já sim. mas preciso setar isso na configuração do PHP pois existem muitas querys com esse problema.

Comment: É quase o mesmo problema dessa pergunta: [Problemas para converter data mon dd yyyy hh:mm](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88760/91) e usa a mesma API `mssql_*`.

Comment: Você precisa da hora?

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($databanco);

Answer (score 2):

Altere sua query para o código abaixo:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120) AS DATA
```

Como resultado você terá algo como:

```
2015-10-02 13:45:05
```