# Formatar data no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer um SELECT em meu banco de dados SQL Server 2008 e não estou conseguindo.

Preciso converter uma data para o formatado `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`, porem preciso converter de alguma forma que funcione em qualquer SQL Server a partir do 2008.

Comment: Isso aqui talvez resolva: [Problemas para converter data mon dd yyyy hh:mm](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88778/91) em qual formato vem a data?

Comment: minha data no banco esta salva assim: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss e ela vem uma data normal dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: teria como postar seu SELECT ?

Comment: @Phiii_Cunha, tratar os dados na sua aplicação não seria uma opção?

Comment: Tratei meu retorno para eu passar yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss ... funcionou, mas queria passar yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss para manter o padrão. O SELECT em si é bem simples SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Campo > 0 AND Convert(varchar, DataHora, 120) = '2016-03-15 16:50:25'

Answer (score 0):

Esse codigo abaixo é totalmente funcional.
Veja que o convert é pra varchar, mas o tipo DateTime recebe valores de varchar sem problemas.

```
select convert(varchar,getdate(),121)
```

Outra coisa que você poder ver é a formatação de datas por sessão, dentro do comando sql server

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Campo > 0 AND Convert(varchar,DataHora,103) = '2016-03-15 16:50:25'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Formate sem o separador

Se o seu campo é `DateTime` você não precisa fazer conversões para `varchar` para colocar um `WHERE`, basta enviar a data no formato `'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss'` que o SQL Server irá reconhecer independente da versão ou do `DATEFORMAT` que estiver no servidor.

Se o campo é apenas do tipo data, basta estar no formato `'yyyyMMdd'`

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Campo > 0 AND DataHora = '20160315 16:50:25'
```

Ou, se o campo for apenas de data:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Campo > 0 AND Data = '20160315'
```

O problema com consultas que envolvem data é que você deve lembrar que se o tipo incluí data e hora, você só terá o resultado de igualdade apenas se a data e a hora forem iguais. Se quiser fazer uma busca só na data independente da hora, terá que fazer um WHERE com uma faixa, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Campo > 0 AND DataHora >= '20160315' AND DataHora < '20160316'
```